# run silex or slim with wordpress

Tags: plugins, rest-api

I am running a theme on WordPress.  In this theme, I am making some AJAX calls where I am expecting some response.  (http://example.com/capis/v0/packages/)

To serve above http calls I am using silex as http server.

index.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Silex\Application;

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->POST('/capis/v0/packages/', function(Application $app, Request $request) {
            # logic            
            return new Response('HELLO');
            });
$app->run();
```

I am using php to run a server on 8080 port which is serving data to ajax calls.

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t web web/index.php
```

Now I want to serve these Ajax calls from using WordPress only. I do not want to run specific php server.

Comment: Seems like more server-side question. If you want allow only requests from your local WordPress installation I suppose you need to configure out your server :)

Comment: I would highly recommend using the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) instead of Silex.

Comment: Besides the REST API mentioned by @kraftner, you can also have a look into the [Themosis](https://framework.themosis.com/) framework.

Comment: For a short example see ie https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/301493
For me https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#examples was very useful.

Comment: You could use WP-REST API or you can make custom API using wp_ajax action. [here is official doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))

Answer (score 1):

There's little that you can do with the Silex server that can't be done through Wordpress but it takes a bit of effort to get WP to respond to AJAX calls.

The first step is to make the call available through AJAX.  This requires adding a line to your functions.php file similar to

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax_call', 'onno_update_my_ajax_call');
```

if this call will be made for guests and customers (i.e. not ADMIN), you'll also need the line.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_call', 'my_ajax_call');
```

which does the same thing but is more inclusive.

The next step is to create the ajax calls.  You don't give an example of such a call so all I can do is advise you to look at the docs for [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).  WP has a comprehensive set of calls for retrieving info from the database and for complex queries, you can always use $wpdb->query() which will run arbitrary SQL for you.

The AJAX logic goes in the function my_ajax_call() and the result should be placed into an array or object.  The final line of your function should be a call to wp_send_json_success($return) where $return is the object/array of information to be returned.

Using this system, I've been able to add pages to the wp_admin section to allow shop owners to build purchase orders for restocking from WooCommerce data and a side-load gallery for variations (Woo only allows a gallery for the parent).

Here's a quick example:

```
function my_ajax_call() {
    $return['data'] = date('Y-m-d');
    wp_send_json_success($return);
    wp_die();
}
```

And then in the javascript, more steps are necessary.  For one thing, you'll need the WP AJAX URL which is usually `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` but can vary somewhat.  It's often made available to Javascript as the global ajaxurl or might be tucked away in another object like `woocommerce.ajaxurl`.  You'll need to construct a Javascript object with an action element that points to your function and any other variables you might need to pass to the AJAX call.  For example:

```
data = {'action':'my_ajax_call'}
```

or

```
data = {'action':'my_ajax_call', 'todo':'getDate'}

(function($){
    $.ajax{
        url:ajaxurl,
        data: data,
        success: function(trn) {$('#data').html(trn.data)}
})(jQuery)
```

HTH

Comment: For some further wordpress and ajax research can I suggest having a read of the articles created by Tom McFarlin, he's v.knowledgable about wordpress and has some good posts on ajax specifically [https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tom+mcfarlin+ajax&oq=tom+mcfarlin+ajax&aqs=chrome..69i57.13229j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8]