# "rest_no_route" - Debug error

Tags: api, rest-api, endpoints

I am using Wordpress `4.9.5` and I want to create a custom endpoint  like the following:

```
<?php
add_action('rest_api_init', 'miningRigsRoutes');

function miningRigsRoutes()
{
    register_rest_route('miningRigs/v1', 'createRig', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::CREATABLE,
        'callback' => 'createMiningRig',
    ));

    register_rest_route('miningRigs/v1', 'allRigs', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'allMiningRigs',
    ));
}

function createMiningRig($data)
{
    //var_dump($data);
    //print_r($data);
    return "Thanks for using the API";
}

function allMiningRigs() {
    return "All mining Rigs";
}
```

The url I am using is:

`http://localhost/wordpress-site/wp-json/miningRigs/v1/createRig/`

However, I get the following in return for the `post-route`:

```
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}
```

The `get-route` is working perfectly fine!

I am currently do not use any third party plugins.

Any suggestions how to debug this error for the `post-route`? From my code, everything looks alright!

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: with `CREATABLE` this endpoints works only with `POST`. you can use e.g. `"methods" => "GET, POST",` to use it with GET and POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not GET on a POST only rest callback. The code below creates a POST call only

```
register_rest_route('miningRigs/v1', 'createRig', array(
    'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::CREATABLE,
    'callback' => 'createMiningRig',
));
```

Check http://localhost/wordpress-site/wp-json/miningRigs/v1 which shows you can only POST on **createRig**

I just copy/paste you code + added the https://pressupinc.com/blog/2013/07/minimum-viable-wordpress-plugin/ then enabled the plugin on 4.9.5 and it works like expected on a WP 4.9.5

Comment: i think the combination of mmm comment and your answer will give a good answer. Right now it is not clear from the question how `POST` is related here, so maybe worth explaining further.

Comment: I added your code snippet. 'WP_REST_SERVER::CREATABLE' is equivalent with a HTTP POST when visiting the mentioned URL

Comment: Curious about permissions etc I read the API of which https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#examples just extends WP_REST_Controller which probably safes you from building your own GET all and filtering conditions.